# Is there a digital camera that is able to save people bounding boxes?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, metadata, camera-recommendation, xmp, face-detection

I am looking for digital cameras that are able to recognize faces(automatically or by user input) and save those as tags in XMP using either *Microsoft Photo 1.2 Schema* or *Metadata Working Group - Region Schema* or both.

Are there cameras out there that support those XMP tags?

Comment: possibly related - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14739/can-face-detection-information-be-extracted-from-the-exif-data-on-a-canon-sx30

Comment: There is a lot of software that can generate the boxes. Maybe you would be better of adding the boxes in when you process the images from the camera?

Comment: Maybe you could write a translator application to get the info in the format you need? Cameras with Face-Recognition store the info somewhere but probably not in XMP at this time.

Answer (score 1):

My Canon S110 can recognize faces and identify them! There's a menu in the camera for saving up to 10 faces.

As far as I know, they are put as tags in Lightroom when I import the photos in my computer.

Comment: "As far as I know..."   Can you look?

Comment: Well it is presently at Canon Repair Center but as soon as I get it back I'm gonna look into it.

Answer (score 1):

My comparatively old Panasonic DMC-FZ200 (released 2012) has this in the manual for play mode:

```
[Face Rec Edit]
You can delete or change the information relating to Face Recognition for the selected picture.
1 Select [Face Rec Edit] on the [Playback] menu. (P52)
2 Press 3/4 to select [REPLACE] or [DELETE] and then press [MENU/
SET].
3 Press 2/1 to select the picture and then press [MENU/SET].
4 Press 2/1 to select the person and then press
[MENU/SET].
5 (When [REPLACE] is selected) Press 3/4/2/1 to
```

[...]

```
Note
• When all Face Recognition information in a picture has been canceled, the picture will not be
categorized using Face Recognition in [Category Selection] in [Filtering Play].
```

So it does recognise several faces (I think you can store about 10 faces it should recognize by name) and will prioritise them when doing face-based focusing.  It will also label them on playback and allow selective playback of images containing them.

I haven't used this functionality so I don't know which form it is stored in: I would suspect some EXIF tags getting used rather than XMP (but of course this should be reasonably straightforward to convert).  Since this sounds like the kind of feature earning a checkmark in camera tests and since it already was available in 2012, I should be surprised if it isn't buried somewhere in the menus of most current-day offerings in some more or less useful manner.

Answer (score 0):

Nikon RAW holds the face detection data but does not do any actual recognition since it's too computationally expensive to do in camera.

Windows Live Photo Gallery will do the face recognition and will output to XMP according to [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918215012/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pix/archive/2008/10/02/why-people-tags.aspx).

Answer (score -3):

Advancements in the photographic field is drastic but such an idea has not struck yet :)
but there is definitely an alternative to recognize faces and add tags to the pictures.

Picasa photo editor has this function.

http://support.google.com/picasa/answer/156272?hl=en

Comment: Does that save them in Picasa or into the image metadata ?

Comment: @MikeW: AFAIK, Picasa (used to) store everything in the images themselves as one of its selling points is not using a library system: everything is solidly mapped to a folder structure.